# How can I change scenes when the player touches another CollisionShape2D in Godot 3.5?

Tags: collision-detection, scene, gdscript, godot-3

I need to know how I can change scenes in Godot 3.5 when the player ***touches*** another `CollisionShape2D`.

I've tried this:

```
extends Area2D

func _on_Area2D_body_entered(_body):
    print("changed")
    get_tree().change_scene("res://World2.tscn")
```

`print()` is to check if it has changed the scene and it did change the scene but it seems to change right from the start.

I also got this error:

> Missing connected method '_on_Area2D_body_shape_entered' for signal 'body_shape_entered' from node 'World/Area2D' to node 'World/Area2D'

Comment: The error tells you Godot is looking for a method `_on_Area2D_body_shape_entered` that was connected to a signal, but the code you show has `_on_Area2D_body_entered` instead. I'm not sure how that happened, but I'm guessing it is an incorrectly connected signal, or a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason why your scene transition triggers immediately is the signal you're currently intercepting.

I assume the method `_on_Area2D_body_entered()` is in the player script. The `body_entered()` signal is emitted when a `PhysicsBody2D` or a `TileMap` enters an `Area2D`, so your player is probably triggering it by simply standing on the floor, if any.

> ...when the player ***touches*** another `CollisionShape2D`.

Actually, `CollisionShape2D` only provide a collision shape to `CollisionObject2D`-derived Nodes. While based on *CollisionShapes*, collisions occur among *Nodes*. There are two main categories of collision signals: areas and bodies. They allow you to know **just** what area/body a given Node collided with, or **both** the involved area/body **and** which particular collision shape collided.

If your colliding object only uses one `CollisionShape2D` and requires no physics, you can keep things simple and detect the `area_entered()` signal instead. Moreover, you can move the scene transition logic to the "teleporter" Node in a new script, since scene changing has now become its responsibility, and the player will implement the logic for collisions that only affect its movement or interaction.

Here's a handy script for your "teleporter" object, which in fact I called *Teleporter* and saved as a separate scene:

```
extends Area2D


export var go_to_scene: PackedScene


func _on_Teleport_area_entered(area: Area2D):
    if area.name == "Player":
        get_tree().change_scene_to(go_to_scene)
```

In the Teleporter scene (NOT your level scene), if you connect the `area_entered()` signal to the method above, you'll have it detect the player entering its collision shape wherever you instantiate the teleporter. Also, exporting the `go_to_scene` variable as a `PackedScene` allows you to quickly select the next scene from the Inspector, by clicking on its input field, then *Quick Load*:

[image]

Comment: The method _on_Area2D_body_entered() is actually in the Area2D script. will it affect your given guide?

Comment: and also as theraot mentioned. it was wrong for me to use the method "body_entered",

Comment: but thanks for your help!

Comment: "The method (...) is actually in the `Area2D` script". So is mine. I gave the scene-changing object [a different name](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-property-name) than its base component type to avoid ambiguity. In my answer, the *Player* and the *Teleport* Nodes are both `Area2D`s, and none is using `body_entered` methods.

Comment: "Will it affect your given guide?". Not at all. Just turn the logic around and check in the *Player*'s script whether the `Area2D` it is colliding with is named "*Teleporter*" (or any other name of your choice). However, this will soon clutter the *Player* script if multiple collision checks are performed there only. That's why I suggest [the scene transition logic belongs in the *Teleporter* script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).